# Comparison of strings using .substr()

Tags: c++, string, comparison

```
std::string text {"Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled pepper."};
std::string phrase {"Got to pick a pocket or two."};
for (size_t i{}; i < text.length() - 3; ++i)
 if (text.substr(i, 4) == phrase.substr(7, 4))
 std::cout << "text contains " << phrase.substr(7, 4) 
 << " starting at index " << i << std::endl;
```

I know why -3 is written in

```
size_t i{}; i < text.length() - 3; ++i
```

because that is the maximum number of searches to search the string "pick". But wouldn't it be better to just write

```
size_t i{}; i < text.length(); ++i
```

without the -3... That would make the code way more flexible and you can input any text you want in `string phrase` without having to worry about the **-ve integer part in the for loop**... I did just that and removed the -3 part and it searched just fine.
Will there be a case where the code will not work if I remove the -ve integer part...

Comment: try changing `phrase.substr(7, 4)` to `phrase.substr(1, 4)` and see

Comment: C++ wouldn't cache values returned from operators\members calls like C# would in similar context. You'd want to precalculate search length  and string  `phrase.substr(7, 4)` (assuming they stay same).

Comment: You'd really want a `string_view` for this - this might be old code.

Comment: Whatever you decide, `i + n < text.length()` is better than `i < text.length() - n` for non-negative `n`. Else you'll get into trouble with unsigned arithmetic.

Comment: @sittsering Ummmm... The substring obtained from `phrase.substr(1, 4)` will not search no because "ot t" doesn't exist in the string text.

Comment: @Bathsheba May I ask what is `n' in the context of my code...

Comment: @GuruRandapa 3, innit.

Comment: @GuruRandapa *The substring obtained from phrase.substr(1, 4) will not search no because "ot t" doesn't exist in the string text.* that's not how your code works. it'll search whether it exists or not. The reason -3 is written is you are finding substring of size 4. So if you are finding substring of `phrase` in `text` which doesnt exist , it'll give issues. The length of `text` is 43, so when it comes to `text.substr(i, 4)` where i>= 40, there'll be error.

Comment: @sittsering Well, I ran this code 
```
std::string text {"Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled pepper."};
std::string phrase {"r."};
for (size_t i{}; i < text.length(); ++i)
 if (text.substr(i, 4) == phrase.substr(0, 2))
 std::cout << "text contains " << phrase.substr(0, 2)
 << " starting at index " << i << std::endl;
```
and it searched the element without a problem. I know it should text.substr( i , 2 ) but even when searching with 4 elements at a time. The search ran just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The '-3' part in the for loop stands for the several last not fitting suffixes in the text variable. If you're searching for a pattern of size 4, there's no point in checking if suffixes 'r', 'er' and so forth are valid, because their size isn't 4. The situation when your code may behave unexpected though is when phrase.substr(7, 4) will return a substring of size 3 or less. In that case there may be a situation when text variable's suffix is equal to a searched pattern, but it won't be found because of a '-3' part.

Comment: But for two strings to be equal their length should also be equal so such a situation would never arrive, right?

Comment: In case you remove the '-3' part, yes. The logic behind the '-3' part is to skip some pointless iterations, but that doesn't work as expected in all cases, as I pointed out in the answer. The best solution to that would be to refactor the code, using the std::string::find method, for example. It returns just what you need: the position of the first character of the first match.

Comment: Thank You very much! I now understand it completely.